# column "a.ParcelID" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT "a.ParcelID", "a.PropertyAddress", "b.ParcelID", "b.PropertyAddress",            isnull("a.PropertyAddress", "b.PropertyAddress")
from data "a"
join data "b"
on "a.ParcelID" = "b.ParcelID"
and "a.ID" <> "b.ID"    
where "a.PropertyAddress" is null
```

for the above code its showing me error any solutions

```
ERROR:  column "a.ParcelID" does not exist
LINE 4: on "a.ParcelID" = "b.ParcelID"
       ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "a.ParcelID" or the column "b.ParcelID".
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the table alias when using the dreaded double quotes, e.g. `a."ParcelID"` or `a."PropertyAddress"`

In general it's recommended to avoid column names that require quoting to begin with.